# Balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and diameter

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Problem:

Let $A$ $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty set with finite diameter. Show that there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\subseteq B(x,2\operatorname{diam})$

May I have some hints?

Comment: Hint: pick $a \in A$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D = \operatorname{diam}(A) < \infty$. Let $x \in A$, then

$$\forall a \in A: d(x,a) \le \sup\{d(u,v): u,v \in A\} = D < 2D, \text{ or equivalently } a \in B(x,2D)$$

Hence $A \subseteq B(x,2D)$.